# Как в JavaScript работает дата?

Tags: javascript, дата

В консоли браузера Chrome воссоздаю реальную ситуацию:

```
var today = new Date(); // undefined
today.getDate() // 24
let date = today // undefined
date.getDate() // 24
let thisDay = date.getDay() // undefined
thisDay // 4
date.setDate(date.getDate() - thisDay + 1) // 1624278668009
date.getDate() // 21
today.getDate() // 21
```

Вопрос: почему поменялась дата в today?

Comment: потому что `setDate` меняет объект

Comment: И потому что в JS объекты [копируются по ссылке](https://learn.javascript.ru/object-copy). Поэтому у вас `date` и `today` это один и тот же объект.

Comment: @Alexey Ten, добавьте ответ, чтобы я отметил.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Спасибо, [Alexey Ten](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/190728/alexey-ten).

> date и today это один и тот же объект

Недостаток фундаментальных знаний налицо. Увы мне.